# How to Bind related Dropdownlist in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Grid view, whenever I select  1st dropdownlist i.e. subject i want to bind related teachers name on second dropdownlist only one subject and teacher will updated dropdownlist is inside itemtemplate.

eg

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <HeaderTemplate>
         Friday
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubjectFr" runat="server">
         </asp:DropDownList>
         <br />
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTeacherFr" runat="server">
         </asp:DropDownList>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: can you edit your question..It does not make any sense..

Comment: From where ur getting the Subject and teacher value DB.?Or nay Dictionary...Show the source code..means C# code

Answer (score 0):

If u want u change the Drop down list value of second based on first Drop down list selected value.. that should write in selected Index changed event with auto post back = "true"